# How can I unpack an old Amazon AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A long time ago, I put together a pretty complex (but quickly built) web app running on an EC2 farm. At some point I abandoned it, and shut down the farm, and I had a copy of the web app code on my local desktop. Before I had a chance to copy it somewhere safe, I had a bad crash, and lost those files. I thought they were gone forever.

Recently, I was digging around in my S3 buckets, and found a backup of the Apache AMI I had created on EC2. It consists of a manifest.xml file, and 85 x 10.5MB segments:

- appname-apache_x64-201103310802.manifest.xml
- appname-apache_x64-201103310802.part.00 ~ 84

Is there any way to extract the files from this AMI? I've dug around a bit, and I've seen some documentation on ec2-unbundle, but it looks like I might need a private key, and I'm not sure if or where I would still have that (or if I could regenerate it). Perhaps I'm over-thinking it?

Any help hugely appreciated!

**Update:** I tried relaunching the AMI as some have suggested. I went into my AWS console, and went to register a new AMI under the EC2 console. When I put in the path to the manifest.xml file (which hasn't moved), I get the following error:

> HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) response for URL scalr-images-us-972708971173.s3.amazonaws.com:80/…: check your manifest path is correct and in the correct region.

What's weird is that if I copy and paste the URL from the error into a browser (after setting open permissions on the file), the browser downloads the XML file no problem. So why isn't AWS seeing it?

Comment: Why not just launch an instance from that AMI and get the files off that instance?

Comment: is that possible with files in this format? how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should do:

- Launch a micro instance from that AMI (I hope it was registered on your account).
- Let the setup complete.
- Login to that instance.
- Grab the files that you want to your local machine.
- Kill/terminate this instance.
- DONE!

Comment: it was registered on my account (i believe... definitely my aws account, managed via scalr.net). how would i launch an instance from the ami though? do i need to upload it somewhere? and then how do i make an ec2 instance use it?

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.ipov.net/apps/support/cosolvent/ccs-installation/ccs-aws-launch-ec2-instance/) and see if you were able to launch an instance.

Comment: I logged into my AWS account, and tried to register the AMI under the EC2 panel, but had some strange issues I'll note in the original question.

Comment: @KevinCogill the XML says there is no such bucket, are you sure there is a bucket??? And that contains the list of chunks of .xml files?

Comment: @KevinCogill, If nothing works, try [this package](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-unbundle.html) and see if you can fetch your files.

Comment: Looks like I managed to register the AMI after making all parts of the AMI world-accessible. I'm downloading the files now via SCP. Thanks!